# API Design Architechture - Reverse Gateway?

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core, api-design

We are building a large web api (200+ calls). After it got so big, we separated it out into multiple smaller api's. This made sense because we had multiple products that the customer might not have purchased.

So we now have an api per product, however, each api needs the same basic architecture - the connection to the database and all of the custom logic for authentication and retrieving tokens needs to be the same for every api. We do not want them to have to get a new token for each api.

We thought about a gateway api, but we are using swashbuckle\swagger and I don't see a way for that to work with the gateway.

The current plan is to make a token api that does all of the token and authentication. The user would call the token api to get a token, and then, when the user calls each of the product apis, those apis would then call the token api to validate the token. Is this good idea? I'm worried about performance of the api when calling another api. We have a mobile app that will be hitting these api's heavily, along with normal customer usage.

Comment: Identity Server 4 is built and designed for this, It shouldn't be too much of a perfomance hit if you host the applications on the same machine and use netpipe to communicate

Comment: Wonderful, I'll look into this. Thanks.

Comment: There’s no need to call the other api, you can issue a token from a token service and then validate it with middleware in each api. You may have to navigate issues around token renewal and key rotation however. Of course validating a token isn’t free (and presumably doing some form of authorisation, possibly involving some claims from the token) but I guess you’re already doing this in some form already.

Comment: I'm new to .net and C# so this might be a stupid question, but what do you mean by service? Do you mean a console application sitting on the IIS server? Also, yes we are already doing token validation in middleware, so it wouldn't be too much effort to call something else in it's place.

Comment: I shouldv'e researched before asking that previous question... anyways - a shared service seems like exactly what I need. Thanks.